# getting the number of clients from mqtt (via topic $SYS/broker/clients/total) nest js

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a database (MongoDB) of different servers and I need to look at the number of clients for each mqtt server in the background (you will see that I separate them). To begin with, server.schema.ts:

```
//server.schema.ts
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema({ timestamps: false, versionKey:false })
export class server {
  @Prop()
  protocol: string; 

  @Prop()
  totalclients: string; 

  @Prop()
  status: boolean; 
  
  @Prop({ type: Object }) 
  data: Record<string, unknown>;

}

export type serverDocument = server & Document;
export const serverSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(server);
```

usepi.service.ts (only what concerns the problem):

```
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { server } from './schemas/server.schema';
import * as mqtt from 'mqtt'

@Injectable()
export class UsepiService {

    private readonly logger = new Logger(UsepiService.name);
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(server.name) private readonly serverModel: Model<any>,
    ) {
        this.startPollingForMqttServers()
    }

 async startPollingForMqttServers(): Promise<void> {
        const mqttServers = await this.serverModel.find({ protocol: 'mqtt' });
        mqttServers.forEach(server => {
            const client = mqtt.connect(`mqtt://${server.data.ip}:${server.data.port}`);
            client.on('connect', () => {
                const subscribeToClientsTotal = () => {
                    client.subscribe('$SYS/broker/clients/total', (err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error('Subscription error:', err);
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                };
                client.on('message', async (topic: string, message: Buffer) => {
                    if (topic === '$SYS/broker/clients/total') {
                        const totalClients = parseInt(message.toString());
                        console.log(`Total clients connected of ${server.data.title}: ${totalClients}`);
                        try {
                            const dbServer = await this.serverModel.findById(server.id);
                            if (!dbServer) {
                                console.error('Server not found in the database');
                                return;
                            }
                            if (totalClients !== dbServer.totalclients) {
                                await this.serverModel.findByIdAndUpdate(server.id, { totalclients: totalClients });
                                console.log(`Total clients count updated for server ID ${server.id}: ${totalClients}`);
                            }
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error('Error updating total clients count:', error);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }      
}
```

I make a selection from the records by the protocol -> header and subscribe to the topic responsible for the number of connections. When the application starts, it shows everything correctly. After unsubscribing some device, it shows everything correctly. As soon as someone else connects to the broker, I start receiving an endless number of messages on the topic, where the number of connections grows each time. I use mosquito.

```
2023-12-01 23:38:14 Total clients connected of Nameserver: 5
2023-12-01 23:38:20 Total clients connected of Nameserver: 4
2023-12-01 23:38:26 Total clients count updated for server ID 656a17f014a7001438edd19b: 5
2023-12-01 23:38:30 Total clients count updated for server ID 656a17f014a7001438edd19b: 6
2023-12-01 23:38:33 Total clients count updated for server ID 656a17f014a7001438edd19b: 7
2023-12-01 23:38:40 Total clients count updated for server ID 656a17f014a7001438edd19b: 8
.. and so on indefinitely
```